# Gems install under vendor/bundle in rails app local testing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

I have a rails app that I'm running locally where the gems are installed in the vendor/bundle directory.  I want to add some debugging statements to a gem and then test it locally. I'm running `bundle exec rackup config.ru` to run the server. I've tried rerunning bundle install before starting the application, but that still doesn't seem to pick up my changes. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you building the gem again after making modifications to it by running `gem build gemname.gemspec` ?

Comment: No do I need to do that? I thought by updating the source directory the changes would get picked up, but I guess that makes sense that you'd have to rebuild the gem.

Comment: I run `gem build gemname.gemspec` but still get the same issue from before. It doesn't seem to pick up the local changes that I've made in vendor/bundle

Comment: In your main application gemfile, are you providing the path to the local gem directory? like `gem "gemname", path: "vendor/bundle/gemname"` ? if you do this you don't need to each time build and install the gem when you modify it, otherwise you have to both `build` and `install` the gem after modifying it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `bundle show --paths` will print out exactly where Bundler is loading your gems from, so you can double-check that against the files you are editing.

As a shortcut, `bundle open <gemname>` will open that gem's directory in your editor of choice (whatever your `EDITOR` environment variable is set to). You can then edit it directly there.

There is normally no need to re-run `bundle install` or rebuild the gem when you edit files this way.